# simplify query for additional data using Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

i have a query which require additional information based on the result of first query. Here is the code

```
$params = DB::select('SELECT vpl_ppid, vpl_name, vpl_display, vpl_filter 
                      FROM vw_parameter_list 
                      WHERE vpl_slug = :type', ['type' => $type]);
foreach ($params as $param) {
    $pd_vals = DB::select('SELECT * FROM parameter_distinct_value WHERE pd_ppid = :vpl_ppid ORDER BY pd_value', ['vpl_ppid' => $param->vpl_ppid]);          
    $param->value_list = $pd_vals;
}
```

as you can see above, i simply create a new array (`$param->value_list`) to load more data into it.
how to simplify the query by eliminating the query inside the `foreach` in order to achieve speed and same output as above. Thanks

Comment: If you have models, you could user relationship for that https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships

Comment: I don't use the models as it been adapted from legacy db

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery:

```
$results = DB::select('
    SELECT * 
    FROM 
        parameter_distinct_value 
    WHERE pd_ppid IN(
        SELECT vpl_ppid FROM vw_parameter_list WHERE vpl_slug = :type
    ) 
    ORDER BY pd_value
', ['type' => $type]);
```

Or a join

```
$results = DB::select('
    SELECT pdv.*
    FROM
        parameter_distinct_value pdv
        INNER JOIN vw_parameter_list vpl ON vpl.vpl_ppid = pdv.pd_ppid
    WHERE vpl.vpl_slug = :type
    ORDER BY pdv.pd_value
', ['type' => $type]);
```

Comment: actually i have a few fields needed when query table `vw_parameter_list` and as you can see from the laravel's collection (`$params`), I simply create additional `key` to load up more data into it. I have revise my question above